# Jquery ui tooltip doesn't reopen after disabling automatic closing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code for opening a tooltip:

**javascript:**

```
$(window).ready(function () {
            $('.tooltips').bind("mouseleave", function (event) {
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }).tooltip({
                tooltipClass: "tooltip",
                position: {
                    my: "center bottom-20",
                    at: "center top",
                    using: function (position, feedback) {
                        $(this).css(position);
                        $("<div>")
                            .addClass("arrow")
                            .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                            .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                            .appendTo(this);
                    }
                },
                content: function () {
                    return $(this).prop('title');
                }
            });
            $(document).on('click', 'span.close', function () {
                $(this).closest('.tooltip').hide();
            });
        });
```

**html:**

```
<p>Testing hover <a href="#" class="tooltips" title="<h4>TITLE<span class='close'>X</span></h4><p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>">tooltip</a></p>
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/e1wxzhg7/

Which only closes, for now, when clicking the `span.close` "button". When re-hovering the tooltip trigger nothing happens. I suppose it's because of the `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` function.

How can I re-activate/re-initiate the tooltip after closing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you are hiding the generated tooltip HTML using the CSS property of `display: none`, as you're calling `hide()` on it. This means that it does get called again, however it is invisible. Instead, you should use the built-in `close` option of the tooltip library. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'span.close', function () {
    $('.tooltips').tooltip('close');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/e1wxzhg7/2/)

Comment: Aah stupid of me. This however closes all tooltips opened. This isn't a major issue though. Thanks for the answer! PS: apparently I have to wait a few minutes before accepting your answer :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.